# How to update DOM in React.js after submitting form

Tags: reactjs, forms

My application is supposed to display notes and allow the user to add a note by submitting a form. When I submit the form I'm not getting a console log from my function that gets all the posts from the server. However, when I refresh the page or omit event.preventDefault() it displays the latest post. How do I make sure getAllNotes() runs after a successful post to the server?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allNotes: [],
      title: "",
      body: ""
    };
  }

  getAllNotes() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/allnotes")
      .then(res => {
        const allNotes = res.data;
        console.log("res.data ", res.data);
        this.setState({ allNotes });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  // update state based on name of input
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { title, body } = this.state;
    const time = moment(Date.now()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/addnote", { title, body, time })
      .then(result => {
        this.getAllNotes();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });

    // this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  deleteNote(id) {
    // <-- declare id parameter
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete/${id}`) // <-- remove ;
      .then(() => {
        // Issue GET request after item deleted to get updated list
        // that excludes note of id
        this.getAllNotes();
      })
      .then(res => {
        const allNotes = res.data;
        this.setState({ allNotes });
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllNotes();
  }

  render() {
    const { allNotes, title, body } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <Home allNotes={allNotes} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/AddNote"
            render={() => (
              <AddNote
                title={title}
                body={body}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/EditNote" render={() => <EditNote />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const AddNote = ({ title, body, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
            Notes App
          </Link>
        </Navbar.Brand>
      </Navbar>
      <h1>Add Note</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>
            Title
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              name="title"
              placeholder="Title"
              value={title}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>
            Note
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              name="body"
              rows="3"
              value={body}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default AddNote;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code for the  `Home` component `<Home allNotes={allNotes} deleteNote={this.deleteNote} />`?

It's possible that `Home` only displays its notes on initialization (i.e. it's only in the constructor of Home that Home sets its `allNotes` props to be its state) which could explain why you need to refresh the page before you can see the latest post.

BTW: I think you accidentally copy and pasted the `App` code class twice (but for the duplicate `App` code, you could just edit it to make it the `Home` code :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to worry about "how to update DOM". React does this for you. Whenever props or state change, React will re-render your component with the new values. The only exception being pureComponents, which won't re-render if the new props and state are exact same as the previous props and state.

Can you confirm that the getAllNotes callback is firing after posting to the new note? The fact that it works after refresh only means the componentDidMount is working as expected.

Comment: You are totally right, it was an error on server side